# Clarification of API benefits

Tags: api, iot

While not a code-based question, I feel this question is relevant to the developer community in pursuit of a deeper understanding of API's and their role in business and the IoT at large.

Can someone please expand on the statement below? Other than in-house dev time, how exactly do API's save businesses money and foster agility?

"...APIs save businesses money and provide new levels of business agility through reusability and consistency."

Additionally, while we all know that API's are cool and can be used to build amazing things, I'm seeking to understand this from the perspective of risk vs. reward for a business.

Comment: Certainly interesting, but too broad for SO I would say. Go and find the website of a big player in IoT, I am sure they will give you enough reason why their favourite API is good for you. Here in Germany I would have a look at Bosch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIs benefit larger organizations or distributed organizations with separate business units or functional units.  In that scenario it allows the different functional units to deploy independently assuming you do API versioning.  This has a very substantial work queuing benefit in a larger organization.

In a small organization their benefits are questionable and APIs should probably be extracted from systems as duplication arises or new problems could benefit from old solutions.  Having gone through this transition I can say it's unwise to build APIs without existing applications.

In the context of IoT APIs make a lot of sense because you have largely dumb devices (supercomputers by 1980's standards) that connect back to smart infrastructure.  If that is done in a bespoke or ad-hoc way it's going to be an enormous headache to change things as you release new devices.  With versioned APIs separating the devices and the smart infrastructure you have a greater chance of introducing change without disabling your customers' legacy devices.

Answer (score 0):

In IoT Space, APIs offer the following benefits:

- New device types (e.g. from different vendors) can be easily added to the IoT platform. This saves money, because you as business owner can select from multiple devices and choose the best for your purpose, i.e. the most cost efficient one. (This relates to the API between the device and the platform).
- New applications or new features can be added easily. E.g. in case you need an additional feature, it can be added on top. Even better, you can ask your internal IT or an external system integrator to do the work, again giving you the choice to select the best offer. (This relates to the API between the platform and other application).

From risk viewpoint, APIs do need to be protected as any other endpoint that you expose to the Internet (or Intranet). As minimum, you need authentication (username, password or other means), authentication (access to a subset of the data) and encryption (i.e. use TLS). Depending on your scope, you might need additional governance and API protection (e.g. throttling).